# Showing Foreign key in the ER diagram is Valid or not?

Tags: erd

Showing Foreign key in the ER diagram is Valid or not?

I am showing the foreign key in erd, is this correct?

Comment: Yes it is valid

Comment: what does your diagram look like? show me an example

Answer (score 0):

ER is a conceptual model and it have entity types connected by relationes, it never shows a foreign key.